# Language switching in Hubspot CMS

Tags: html, hubspot, hubl, hubspot-cms

What is the best way to make custom language switcher to the site.

My problem is that I have a site with two language versions and my custom language switcher is a bit problematic I would say. It doesn't work in all pages for some reason and in my opinion is it coded in very complicated way. In our site the language versions are changed via url. For example mycompany.fi/ is the main language version and the mycompany.fi/en/ is for the english version of the site. Here is the code how I switch language currently by just changing the url. In the code it checks the url and also if the page has translated_content. After that I put the site_language and other_language to links so by pressing the link it changes the language.

```
{% if absolute_url is string_containing "/en-us/" %} 
  {% set site_language = 'en'  %} 
  {% set other_language = 'fi' %}
  {% if content.translated_content['fi-fi'] %}
    {% set other_language_url = '/' + content.translated_content['fi-fi'].slug %} 
  {% elif content.translated_content['fi'] %}
    {% set other_language_url = '/' + content.translated_content['fi'].slug %} 
  {% else %}
    {% set other_language_url = '#' %} 
  {% endif %}
{% elif absolute_url is string_containing "/en/" %}
  {% set site_language = 'en'  %}
  {% set other_language = 'fi' %}
  {% if content.translated_content['fi-fi'] %}
    {% set other_language_url = '/' + content.translated_content['fi-fi'].slug %} 
  {% elif content.translated_content['fi'] %}
    {% set other_language_url = '/' + content.translated_content['fi'].slug %} 
  {% else %}
    {% set other_language_url = '#' %} 
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  {% set site_language = 'fi' %}
  {% set other_language = 'en' %}
  {% if content.translated_content['en-us'] %}
    {% set other_language_url = '/' + content.translated_content['en-us'].slug %} 
  {% elif content.translated_content['en'] %}
    {% set other_language_url = '/' + content.translated_content['en'].slug %} 
  {% else %}
    {% set other_language_url = '#' %} 
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm wondering is there any other way to make this happen because for me this seems very complicated solution. I would like to know if there is some global variable or something what defines the current language used in the page.